# Display Image and play corresponding audio

Tags: objective-c

I like to display and image and play corresponding audio file. But it is playing audio files first before displaying. I couldn't figure it what is wrong.

```
-(IBAction)playButton :(id)sender{
    UIImage *imageA = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"];
    UIImage *imageB = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"];

        int randomAlphaNum = arc4random() % 2; 
        NSLog(@"%i", randomAlphaNum);
        switch (randomAlphaNum) {
            case 0:
                 imageView.image = imageA;
                for (int i = 1; i <=5; i++) {
                    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/audioA.wav", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];

                    NSError *error;
                    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:&error];
                    audioPlayer.volume = 0.5;

                    if (audioPlayer == nil)
                        NSLog(@"An audio error occured: \"%@\"", audioPlayer);              
                    else 
                    {
                        [audioPlayer play];
                    }
                    sleep(2);
                }
                return;
                break;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all I wouldn't recommend using `sleep` as it's going to chew up your main thread and make your UI unresponsive. I'd actually be curious if removing it alleviates your issue. There's a chance the app is flying through your code, playing the audio and is hitting the `sleep` command before the app can display the image on the screen. What happens if you remove `sleep` and only iterate through the `for` loop once?